# My Entity Framework update is inserting a new row instead of updating the one I want it to asp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looping through the rows in a database table and updating the account balance of each row if it meets the required conditions.

Instead of the row that meets the condition to be updated alone, it gets updated and a new row with the updated values is also created at the same time with the same query.

I use this same code in the same app to change account balances of single rows and it works perfectly. But when I make calls to it from a foreach loop, the above stated problem occurs:

```
public bool CreditCustomerAccount(CustomerAccount account, decimal amount)
{
        try
        {
            if (account.Type == AccountType.Current || account.Type == AccountType.Savings)
            {
                account.AccountBalance += amount;
            }
            else
            {
                account.AccountBalance -= amount;
            }

            _context.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

It updates the row in question but also creates a new database table entry with the updated details

Comment: try debug and see the primary key(account id) is null or same with the id?

Comment: You must have forgotten to put the [key] attribute in the model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework inserting new rows instead of updating them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711151/entity-framework-inserting-new-rows-instead-of-updating-them)

Comment: Kevin Wong, it has a key. The entry in question gets updated. The issue is just the new entry that's added with the same details. This makes the balance sheet to not add up

Comment: I added it Ross

Answer (score 0):

When you post an entity directly back, EF context knows nothing about it.  Check out the [Attach method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.attach?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) on a DBSet.  From MS DOCS:

> Attaches the given entity to the context underlying the set. That is,
>   the entity is placed into the context in the Unchanged state, just as
>   if it had been read from the database... Attach is used to repopulate
>   a context with an entity that is known to already exist in the
>   database.
>
> SaveChanges will therefore not attempt to insert an attached entity
>   into the database because it is assumed to already be there.

So using Attach before modifying any properties will allow the context to "know" about the object, and any changes would then indicate the object is modified.

Comment: `context.CustomerAccounts.Attach(account);`

Comment: That didn't work too. I had to just do the deduction on the same file and it works fine.